# How to "order" tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs

I'm relatively new to TFS and I've been trying to figure out how to order tasks as follows.

Task 1

Task 2 (requires that Task 1 be completed first)

Task 3 (requires that Task 1 and Task 2 be completed first)

etc

Is there a way to do this?  We are using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well.. I found it.

You can specify that a task is a "Predecessor" or a "Successor" to another task, or multiple tasks when you define the link between the two.

There is some basic info about it at this location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465266

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the tasks are ordered by Backlog Priority then ID. By default the backlog priority is blank and is not available to be updated in the UI for tasks.

You can add the field into the UI by modifying the process template.

I found the easiest way to manage these is to create a view that includes the backlog priority, open it in excel and manage them from there.

Comment: I'm using the backlog priority that you mentioned.  My version is TFS 2013 online version.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP has stated, you can use the "Predecessor" or "Successor" links. However, if you're just looking to set the order of the tasks and keep them as a "Child" of the parent User Story:

1. Run the query in TFS > Open in Microsoft Office > Open in Excel
2. In Excel, show the "Stack Rank" column. The user story will have a stack rank value, but the tasks will not.
3. Set the stack rank for the tasks for each user story.
4. Click the publish button in Excel.

Re-run the query in TFS and the tasks should now be ordered (assuming you have ordered by stack rank).